# Will existing holes in drywall compromise ability to bear load?

Tags: drywall, mounting

I'm hanging a 19 lb mirror onto a wall using two plastic drywall anchors, each rated at 35 lb.  However, I botched some math and accidentally drilled two holes (1/4" diameter) and placed drywall anchors in the wrong location, each 1" away horizontally from where the screws will actually need to be placed.

Do I need to buy spackle and patch these holes before hanging the mirror, in case they are making the wall weaker?  I can also just leave the anchors in place, if the external force they exert on the wall would compensate.  I imagine the mirror falling out and the drywall ripping away, but I don't know whether that's even remotely possible.

If it matters, the correctly-placed holes will be about 57" apart from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spackle provides virtually no strength.

Fortunately for you, putting new holes an inch away will be fine, though the further the better.

Leaving the anchors in will also provide no strength.

Next time, measure twice, drill once.